Converting UUID into some information
I know the title in itself is pretty vague, so let me break it down to what I'm trying to do.
There's a game (to be specific, game on WeChat applets), which requests sprites and files in general from a server upon progressing into that part of the game, and upon doing so, the file will be requested and loaded so you can experience the game (duh).Now I've been using Fiddler to track down those sprites (in other words, datamine) that are requested from the server, however like I said, I have to progress to that part of the game in order for Fiddler to show me the request and URL of the file located in the server (example, https://this.example.com/z38/native/FILENAME.png), and my concern is getting sprites that have not been yet requested from the server by the game.
Upon a close inspection, I have realized that the name of the files are UUIDs, in the form of 8-4-4-4-12, and then a 5 character string after it, separated by a dot, and at last, the extension is put. For example: a0216a6d-b337-426d-aecd-ee8a81801087.f8dfb.jpg (Note: this is a legit example, such file does exist in the server)
And I'm little to clueless as to what to do with that UUID. Which is where my question ends up to, is it possible that this UUID could be keeping some type of information? The 5 character string at the end of the file name can be found inside other files of the game, so it's not a problem. While I have that, I would then need to somehow find the UUID corresponding to that 5 character string. To summarize, two are my questions:

Can I convert the UUID into some type of text, string, integer, unit, or anything that could be some sort of information?
Sub-question, as I realize the format "8-4-4-4-12" consists of 5 parts, is it possible that the 5 character string has to do with any of that? Each character respresnting a part of the UUID respectively?

Thank you for answers, and excuse me If I'm wasting your time by me simply asking in the wrong place, or my post being vague at parts.

I’m voting to close this question because it looks like a UUID - which can't possibly be unique if its value is derived from its content. If its not a UUID, what the value actually is depends on what has been implemented at some random remote site we don't know about.

Short answer: No, and Unlikely.
In more detail: A UUID is used when a programmer needs to guarantee that a specific name will never collide with the name of some other thing. Almost every programmer will take the easy way out and use a "GetUUID" function provided by the host in order to generate that UUID randomly. While it's possible to backtrack from the UUID to find some of the information used to generate it, in virtually every case that information will have nothing to do with the program the UUID is used in. For instance, you could decode a Windows-generated UUID to get a timestamp and the system's default network card MAC address, which has very little to do with the Word document it's embedded in.
To tell the truth, if I was coding this app, I'd be more likely to use the UUID to define the player session, and only the five-character part of the filename would be used to identify the asset. So in your example, a0216a6d-b337-426d-aecd-ee8a81801087.f8dfb.jpg, the actual file that exists on the server would be f8dfb.jpg, the UUID is only used to track that it's your current game session that has requested this, and the server wouldn't use it as part of the filename for the asset to send you. I would actually code it so the server would refuse to forward the asset if it's not appropriate for your game session, if the UUID doesn't correspond to a current game session, or if it has no UUID at all; that would be a basic anti-leech protection scheme.

That really does clear a lot of questions, so I'll assume the 5 character string has nothing to with the 5 sets in UUID? If so, I guess impossible for me to track down them sprites I guess

That would be correct. The five sets in the UUID string is simply a standard representation of the 128-bit UUID. The fact that the following string has five (hex) characters to me suggests only that the programmers were planning for up to 1 million assets.

I seem to have found the solution actually, there are 22-character strings that consist the alphabet, numbers, /, and +, which is base64. Is there any way that the 8-4-4-4-12 format UUID can be converted to a base64 string? Other questions seem to rely on 36-char long UUIDs rather than 32-char long UUIDs, and I would think this can be discussed here, but if not, I can create a new question, let me know

I'll note that a single base64 character encodes 6 bits, so 22 characters would encode at most 132 bits. So yes, possible: treat the UUID as hex representation of 128 bits, then take the resulting 128-bit value and encode with base64. Whether that's what the game's doing I have no clue.
